# Filtering for datetime timestamp column based on just day?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My df has a col as

```
         Time 
2017-10-04 19:00:00
2017-10-03 13:00:00
2017-10-04 04:00:00
2017-10-10 12:00:00
```

If I want to filter for rows that are on 2017-10-10 or after or a date range just based on days without taking time into account is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `df['Time'] > '2017-10-10'`?

Comment: Can you share expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If you set `Time` column as index then you can slice as follows:

```py
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
```

- Dataframe with a given date `date1`: `df = df[date1]`
- Dataframe from date `date1` onwards: `df = df[date1:]`
- Dataframe until date `date1`: `df = df[:date1]`
- Dataframe between a start and an end date  `df = df[start_date:end_date]`

If you don't wan to use `Time` as index, you can do the same operations but with a slightly different sintax on such column:

- Dataframe with a given date `date1`: `df = df[df['Time]==date1]`
- Dataframe from date `date1` onwards: `df = df[df['Time]>=date1]`
- Dataframe until date `date1`: `df = df[df['Time]<date1]`
- Dataframe between a start and an end date  `df = df[df['Time].between(start,end)]`

Answer (score -2):

You can convert a datetime.datetime object to a datetime.date object by using its date() function:

```
variable = variable.date()
```

with variable being your datetime.datetime object.